# Reverse an Array using Collections.reverse() method in java not functioning as expected

Tags: java, arrays, collections, reverse

I was trying to reverse elements in a character array using the Collections.reverse() method in java. It wasn't reversing them so i took an integer array as was used in the example i was referring to with no success

Here is my code

```
int[] intarr = {1,2,3,5,7,8};
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(intarr));
Collections.reverse(Arrays.asList(intarr));
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(intarr));
```

It returns two lists same as the input! what's going wrong here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Arrays.asList(intarr)` doesn't do what you think it does.

Given that `intarr` is a primitive array, it is **not possible** to simply turn this into a list; after all, a `List<int>` is not (yet) legal java.

Thus, that makes a `List<int[]>` (as in, a list of int arrays), with exactly 1 element in it: Your int array. Reversing a 1-size list doesn't do anything as you might surmise.

There is no one-liner answer to this short of using third party libraries.

Comment: You down voted me before I had a chance to down vote you (thankfully). I've never been so wrong on an answer. This is crazy and I would have never guessed. That's not too intuitive.  So `T` the generic parameter becomes `int[]`? because we passed in one array and that's the only way to match up the arguments. Why does it produce a list of singleton arrays rather than just a List with  the original array with it's only element?

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation, i converted the primitive int into it's wrapper class  type and the function is working as expected

Comment: This answer isn't quite correct but of course the gist of it is. The `asList` method returns a `List<int[]>` with the original array in it. I just tested it out for myself.

Comment: @MichaelWelch yes, that’s not intuitive. Making `Arrays.asList` a varargs method was a historical mistake.

Comment: @Holger yeah now that I examine the method signature it's obvious it needs to work the way it does.